# python open cv loading image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to python and open cv. I'm trying to find out how to load an image in opencv with python. Can any one provide an example (with code) explaining how to load the image and display it?

```
import sys
import cv
from opencv.cv import *
from opencv.highgui import *
ll="/home/pavan/Desktop/iff pics/out0291.tif"
img= cvLoadImage( ll );
cvNamedWindow( “Example1”, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cvShowImage( “Example1”, img );
cvWaitKey(10);
cvDestroyWindow( “Example");
```

Answer (score 7):

There have been quite a few changes in the [openCV2](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread) API:

```
import cv
ll = "/home/pavan/Desktop/iff pics/out0291.tif"
img = cv.LoadImage(ll)
cv.NamedWindow("Example", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE )
cv.ShowImage("Example", img )
cv.WaitKey(10000)
cv.DestroyWindow("Example")
```

It is a simpler, quite cleaner syntax!

Also, you don't need trailing `;` à-la-matlab. Last, be careful about the quotes you use.

For the newer openCV3 API, you should see the other answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
image_path = "/home/jay/Desktop/earth.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(image_path)  # For Reading The Image
cv2.imshow('image', img)      # For Showing The Image in a window with first parameter as it's title
cv2.waitKey(0)   #waits for a key to be pressed on a window 
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # destroys the window when the key is pressed
```

Comment: Please add a comment.  Code-only answers leave out context for the readers.

Comment: possible link to openCV3 / python doc for ``imread`` : http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible approaches to this:

1. Using argparse (recommended):

   `import cv2
    import argparse
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()  

    ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True,help = "Path to the image")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())  

    image = cv2.imread(args["image"])`

This will take the image as an argument, will then convert the argument, add it to ap and the load it using the imread function()

To run it.

Go to your required folder

source activate your environment

python filename.py -i img.jpg

2. Hardcoding the image location:

   `import cv2
    img = cv2.imread("\File\Loca\img.jpg")
    cv2.imshow("ImageName",img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Run this similarly, omitting the arguments.